# How to extract filename and add as a column using unix

Tags: unix, append, filenames

I have a bunch of files in a directory i.e.

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

Each file has the same structure
i.e.

```
id,  field
"a", 123
"b", 234
"c", 456
```

I want to append all files (without the headers repeating but create a third column for the file name i.e.

```
id,  field, filename
"a", 123, file1.txt
"b", 234, file2.txt
"c", 456, file3.txt
```

How do I do this in unix?
I can figure out how to extract then name of the file

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -v OFS=", " '
    NR == 1 {print $0, "filename"}
    FNR == 1 {next}
    {print $0, FILENAME}
' file*
```

As you may guess, the `FILENAME` variable contains the name of the current file being processed. The `FNR` variable contains the record number of the current file, and `NR` contains the total number of records processed. So, `NR == 1` will be the first line of the first file

Documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html#Auto_002dset) -- although that's a link to GNU awk, these variables are applicable to all awks